# Fancybox Youtube issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Having real issues using Fancy box to display my YouTube videos. I've followed the instructions from:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Rather than displaying my youtube video in a pop-out window on my website as it's supposed to, it just takes me direct to YouTube instead.

Can anyone help?

JavaScript/Fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css"media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".info").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    helpers : {

        media : {}
    }
});
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="view view-first">  

 <img src="http://www.intelligenthq.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/capital-markets1-360x194.jpg" />
 <div class="mask">  
 <h2>Title</h2>  
 <p>Your Text</p>  
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92c3dX-AoXs" class="info">Play</a>  

    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: what is your problem and what is your question?

Comment: It's not working. Rather than displaying my youtube video in a pop-out window as it's supposed to, it just takes me direct to YouTube instead.

Comment: Do you have jQuery library included before Fancybox scripts?

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Yes, I have the jQuery library included before the Fancybox scripts

Comment: You rather share a link to the page with issue ... otherwise I can see you question closed and unanswered ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the examples it seems that you may have to opt-in to the behavior by including the media helpers:

```
<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
```

By default Fancybox won't perform the transform on such links, even if explicitly enabled on them (because without [`fancybox-media`](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js) it doesn't know how).

Comment: + 1 : that seems to be pretty much the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a copy&paste failure or a typo, but your 2nd `<script/>` tag is not well formed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js</script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this was just a copy and paste issue. The mousewheel script is an optional feature anyhow - so fixing or removing this script doesn't resolve my problem.